# Keeping Two-day Shabbos in the Pacific Islands?

Tags: minhag, shabbat, zemanim, communities, astronomy

What's [this](https://forums.dansdeals.com/index.php?topic=8880.msg1950608#msg1950608) I see about people in the Pacific Islands keeping two days of Shabbos? If it is true: Who, how, since when, and why?